# Gchat invitation automatic?

Tags: google-talk

I got an invitation to Gchat today from someone who cut off contact with me. Before this, we were frequent communicators. I erased all messages and emails from the person a few days ago and erased the contact from my phone. When I logged in to Gmail it said “x would like to invite you to chat” and the yes or no option. I clicked yes. Now this person is listed in my contacts as "invited", implying that I am the one that invited them to chat, not vice versa. Is it possible that Gmail sent me that invitation to chat with this person automatically, without their knowledge? And now that person thinks I invited them now?

Comment: Have a look at this http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74266/does-gchat-automatically-send-out-a-chat-invite whether this helps.

Answer (score 1):

No. The likely explanation for this is that the person (either willingly or mistakenly) invited you to chat and then [revoked that invitation](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/cancel-sent-invitations-gmail-73353.html).

This means that you still received the notification, but once you accepted it the invite no longer existed, meaning Google then requested permission from the other party to start a chat.

This could prove to be quite an awkward situation. You can simply re-iterate their behaviour as follows:

[How to Cancel Sent Invitations to Gmail](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/cancel-sent-invitations-gmail-73353.html)

I hope you manage to resolve things.