# Does Gchat automatically send out a chat invite?

Tags: google-hangouts, google-talk

I decided to remove a contact from my circles and somehow from my chat list. I didn't wish to block this person. I just wanted their name to be gone because we have a history and "out of sight, out of mind" was looking good.

I removed this person, and the next morning when I signed into my Gmail, I had an invitation from this person that said "_____ would like to be able to chat with you. Do you accept?" I hit yes. And now this person is on my list again.

My question is: did this person actually send me a chat invitation? Is it possible that I was removed from their list because they were removed from mine? Is it possible to get an automatic invite because we've chatted previously?

I asked this person if they sent me a chat invite, and they denied it. But they could be lying. So I'm trying to make sense of this.

Comment: Is this about Google Talk or Google Hangouts? They're too very different things, and GTalk has been shut down.

Answer (score 1):

In some circumstances, Gmail may actually be responsible for this behaviour. According to this article:

[Gmail will automatically invite some contacts](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/29795?hl=en)

> If there are other Gmail users whom you frequently email, you'll be able to chat and see each other online without having to send an invitation.

It seems like in your circumstance, the criteria is likely to have been met.

If you don't want Gmail to automatically enable chat privileges with your contacts, follow these steps:

1. Log in to Gmail.
2. Click the gear in the top right .
3. Select Settings.
4. Open the Chat tab, and select Only allow people that I've explicitly approved to chat with me and see when I'm online
5. Click Save Changes

Hopefully this resolves things for you.

Comment: This would happen if the user you have deleted again try to chat with it so in that case it is forcing you to accept the user as friend better block it to avoid further invitations

Answer (score -1):

Ive read all of the tutorials on gchat. However, the explanation "If there are other Gmail users whom you frequently email, you'll be able to chat and see each other online without having to send an invitation." implies that their name would automatically be added to my chat list, not that they would send an invite without actually sending an invite.

This behavior is odd to me.

Has anyone actually tested this out?